# Update value in table 1 based on value in table 2 in MS Access 2010

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have two tables.  The first is LOA report and the second is ACCT.
What i need to do is update a value in LOA with a value a value from ACCT.  I need to compare the user given input from a separate column in LOA to a field in ACCT to determine the proper record to pull the data from.  Below is what i have so far.  Any help would be much appreciated.  I have been working on this for far too long, and I'm bad at admitting when i'm in over my head. I have this working working as an append query.  But what i want to do is update and not append.  The UPDATE syntax is where im having a problem.

```
INSERT INTO [LOA Report] (ID)
SELECT Acct.AcctID
FROM Acct INNER JOIN [LOA report] ON Acct.EmpID = [LOA Report].[Emp ID]
WHERE ((([Acct]![EmpID])=[LOA report]![Emp ID]));
```

Comment: You should always run your actions queries, as "Select" queries first, to ensure that they are filtering the correct table fields - then change them to Update, Append, Delete, Etc.

Comment: thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

In Access the UPDATE query will look like this:

```
UPDATE [LOA Report]
INNER JOIN Acct ON Acct.EmpID = [LOA Report].[Emp ID]
SET [LOA Report].ID = Acct.AcctID
WHERE ((([Acct]![EmpID])=[LOA report]![Emp ID]));
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using update join?

```
update res 
set
res.[colname]=acct.[colname]
from [LOAreport] res JOIN acct ON Acct.EmpID = res.[EmpID] and res.colname=acct.colname
```

Comment: MS Access uses `UPDATE ... INNER JOIN` syntax. A specific `JOIN` must be specified.